# DT outputtable in r Shiny bleeds out of shiny box

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am having an issue where the data for my DT table is "bleeding" past the edge of the box in my fluid row.

Here is the `tabPanel` section

```
tabPanel("Table title", h1('dataset', style = 'color: #23A595'),
                                          p('Here we will have a paragraph of explanatory text to talk about the graphs below. Here we will have a paragraph of explanatory text to talk about the graphs below. Here we will have a paragraph of explanatory text to talk about the graphs below. Here we will have a paragraph of explanatory text to talk about the graphs below. Here we will have a paragraph of explanatory text to talk about the graphs below.', style = 'color: black'),
                                          fluidRow(
                                            box(DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "table"), width = NULL, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary"),
                                          ),
```

When the app is run here is the result of the render DT.

[image]

Here is what the data set looks like.

[image]

The red box highlights the issue.

Here is what i have tried:

First,

```
  output$table<- renderDT(
    
    outputtable,options = list(columns.width = "3px"
    ),
    rownames= FALSE
    
  )
```

Second,

```
fluidRow(box(DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "table"),width = #),
                          )
```

I was under the impression that shiny just automatically calculates the size needed despite window size an such.

in simple terms, shiny creates box + add DT table to box =  box with DT table INSIDE of it.

I want the highlighted issue to not happen what do I need to do?

If there is anything I can add let me know.

Comment: Will be better if you add a small reproducible example.

Comment: of the data set? sure

Comment: Shiny app. Remove the redunant parts.  So that we could run and test your app.

Comment: what version of `DT` are you using? Without a reprex it will be hard for people to test. Off the top, I'd suggest looking at DT options. You can set `scrollX = TRUE`

Comment: The scrollX =TRUE worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The `scrollX` comment above answered the question.